# Proving discontinuity using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

My definition is a function f(x) is discontinuous at a point $x_{0}$ means that

$$
\exists \space \epsilon \space \forall \space \delta \space \exists \space x \space where \space |x-x_{0}| < \delta \space \land \space |f(x)-f(x_{0}| \ge \epsilon
$$

My function
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+1 & if \space x \space is \space irrational \\
2x & if \space x \space is \space rational
\end{cases}
$$

If I’m understanding this correctly then I need to pick an $\epsilon$ and an x. The question asks to show discontinuity at $x_{0} = \sqrt{2}$.

My work -

Let $\epsilon$ = 1, if $\delta \gt 1$ let $x = \pi$ and if $\delta \le 1$, take x = $\frac{\delta}{2}$.

In the first case I get;
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta \land |f(x)-f(x_0)| = |\pi^2 - 2 | < |16-2| \ge 1 = \epsilon 
$$

In the second case I get;
$$
|x-x_0| \lt \delta \land |f(x) -f(x_0)| = | 2(\frac{\delta}{2}) - 3 | = | \delta - 3| \le|1/2 - 3| = 5/2 \ge 1 = \epsilon 
$$

Therefore I would write that $ x = min(\pi, \frac{\delta}{2})$.

Am I understanding this correctly, or have I made a mistake here? Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't take $\pi$ because $|\sqrt 2 - \pi| > \delta$ for any $\delta < \pi - \sqrt 2$.  To be blunt.  No, you don't understand this.  This isn't a matter of picking an $x$.  It's a matter of picking an $\epsilon$ so that no matter what $\delta$ you pick there will always be $x$ that fails.  YOu can't actually pick the $x$ because if you pick a smaller $\delta$ that $x$ won't be in the interval anymore.

Comment: The intuitive things is that for rational numbers near $\sqrt 2$ the $2x$ are all near $2\sqrt 2$.  (Not *equal* to $2\sqrt 2$ because the $x$s are rational but *near* $2\sqrt 2$).  And for the irratioanl numbers nears $\sqrt 2$ the $x^2 + 1$ are near $3$.  So you need to turn that *informal* argument formal.  (Hint:  Let $\epsilon = 3-2\sqrt 2$ ... do you see what would happen then?)

Comment: Another big flaw is to write things like $|f(x)-f(x_0)| <\dots \ge \epsilon,$ which allow to conclude nothing.

Comment: MathJax tip: Writing `if \space x \space is \space irrational` is painfully long, and doesn't look great. Instead, consider using the `\text{}` command. You can write `$\text{if $x$ is irrational}$` to get $\text{if $x$ is irrational}$. Alternatively, you can write `$x \notin \Bbb{Q}$` to get $x \notin \Bbb{Q}$, or `$x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$` to get $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: If $\delta>1$, say $\delta=1.1$ and $x_0=\sqrt{2}=1.41\dots$ then your value $x=\pi$ does not satisfy $|x-x_0|<\delta$. So the choice for $x$ is wrong. The choice of $x$ should be very near to $x_0$ so that the desired goal is met. Why not try $x=1.41$?

Comment: It would be great if you can also describe your thought process behind choosing $\epsilon=1$. One has to understand very clearly how to find an $\epsilon$ which would work here (well that's the problem to be solved). As you can see in the definition of discontinuity this is not arbitrary. +1 for adding relevant details.

Comment: Clearly I don’t have a great understanding of this problem. All of these comments have been very helpful, and I am going to talk to my professor about this problem, so that I can get a clearer image of how to do this type of problem. I think a big problem is I don’t quite fully understand why this is discontinuous, and the definition won’t help me understand that. My guess is that because irrationals are dense around x_0 and rationals are also dense here, that we can find a neighborhood that satisfies the definition of discontinuity. But I’m not sure how to get there at the moment

Answer (score 1):

At $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$, for $x$ *near* $x_0$ and $x$ rational, you have that  
$f(x) = 2x \approx 2x_0 = 2\sqrt{2}.$

At $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$, for $x$ *near* $x_0$ and $x$ irrational, you have that 
$f(x) = x^2 + 1 \approx (x_0)^2 + 1 = 3.$

---

This is where things get very tricky.  This is a Math problem that actually requires sophisticated intuition.

Suppose that you have that

$$|x_1 - x_2| = A.$$

How could you then show that either

$$|x_1 - x_0| \geq \frac{A}{2}$$

or

$$|x_2 - x_0| \geq \frac{A}{2}?$$

**Answer:**
By invoking the triangle inequality.

$$A = |x_1 - x_2| \leq |x_1 - x_0| + |x_0 - x_2|. \tag1 $$

So, if both of the terms on the RHS of (1) above were $~< \dfrac{A}{2},~$ this would force the LHS of (1) above, $|x_1 - x_2|$ to be $< A$, which would contradict the premise that $|x_1 - x_2| = A.$

---

Based on the above analysis, the first thing to do is set

$\epsilon$ to be something like $~\dfrac{1}{40},~$ which is well below

$$[\sqrt{2}^2 + 1] - [2\sqrt{2}] = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}.$$

---

Once this is done, the problem would then reduce to showing that no how small $\delta$ is taken, there will be an $x_1$ and an $x_2,$ both within a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$ such that $x_0, x_1, x_2$ are all distinct from each other, and

$$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| > \frac{1}{20}.$$

This will establish, per the previous analysis, that at least one of the elements in the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$, either $x_1$, or $x_2$ will be such that either

$$|f(x_1) - f(x_0)| < \frac{1}{40} ~~~\text{or}~~~ |f(x_2) - f(x_0)| < \frac{1}{40}.$$

---

This can be done by establishing the following, some or all of which might already be established:

- The function $g(x) = 2x$ is a continuous function at $x_0 = \sqrt{2}.$
- The function $h(x) = x^2 + 1$ is a continuous function at $x_0 = \sqrt{2}.$
- The rational numbers are dense in $\Bbb{R}.$  
  That is, given any $x_0 \in \Bbb{R},$ and given any neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$, 
  no matter how small (positive) $\delta$ is, 
  there exists a rational number not equal to $x_0$ within the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$.
- The irrational numbers are dense in $\Bbb{R}.$  
  That is, given any $x_0 \in \Bbb{R},$ and given any neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$, 
  no matter how small (positive) $\delta$ is, 
  there exists an irrational number not equal to $x_0$ within the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$.